# MVC из сайта

Tags: php

Есть сайт со следующей структурой: 
index.php
images/
css/
style/

Сайт трехколонный. Можно ли сделать из него структуру MVC? Если да, то как?

Comment: у меня один вопрос, а зачем?

Comment: на самом деле файлов много... просто хочу научиться это мутить

Comment: по фразе `Сайт трехколонный` и `MVC` я сразу понял ваши знания, так что рано, это не то что вы думаете, прочтите еще раз что такое mvc, или берите учить сразу фреймворк, например ci or kohana

Comment: Понятно что уровень ниже начального, но начинать лучше правильно. Грабли конечно делают нас сильнее, но боюсь тут не тот случай.

Answer (score 3):

Если хотите научится, то [Создание простой MVC-системы на PHP 5](http://habrahabr.ru/post/31270/)

А если быстро и по нормальному, то `Zend Framework`. И да, не стоит пугаться, там все довольно просто. Мануалов на том же хабре много.

Answer (score 2):

[@Snow](/users/8256/snow), По-моему, правильно начать - это уметь подбирать архитектуру / инструмент под свою задачу, а MVC для трёхколоночного сайта - это да, сильно. Парень наверное думает, что суть MVC в маршрутизации и красивых URL в адресной строке, посмотрев ролики по внесению данных в контроллеры и открытию в браузере их же по имени этого же контроллера.

MVC - это архитектура, созданная для простой масштабируемости проекта (наверное субъективное мнение), почитай побольше о её сути (потому, что судя по формулировке, ты понятия не имеешь о чём спрашиваешь), и только потом приступай к практике. Лучше начать с фреймворков, а потом писать что-то своё.

Comment: А еще лучше стремиться свести *написание своего* к минимуму.

Comment: Ну да конечно лучше без MVC, типичный быдлокод? Вот мы обратились в базу, отфетчили результат и тут же его вывели. В общем это типичный быдлокод, который к сожалению очень часто встречается

Трехколоночный сайт? Ок. Там есть логика? Если нет, то вообще php не нужен, если есть, то эту логику нужно отделить от html! И так вот незаметно мы приходим к MVC